# Exception while Mapping entity to row mapper in spring jdbctemplate

Tags: java, spring

I have a entity object like below  in JPA

```
@Entity
@Table(name="my_version")
public class MyVersion implements EntityKeyOverride {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private Long instanceId;

    @NotNull
    private Long documentId;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 255)
    private String name;


    @NotNull
    private Integer majorVersion;


    @NotNull
    private Integer minorVersion;

    @Size(max = 255)
    private String classification;

    @Size(max = 1500)
    private String description;

    @Size(max = 1500)
    private String title;

    @Size(max = 255)
    private String lifecycle;


    @NotNull
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @DateTimeFormat(style = "LL", iso = ISO.DATE_TIME)
    private Calendar createdDate;

//getter and setter

}
```

I am trying to move away from hibernate/jpa entitymanager to jdbctemplate.I am trying to use my entity as BeanPropertyRowMapper instead of Customrowmapper.

```
jdbcTemplate.query(SQLQueryDescriptorTest, query.toString(), parameterMap, new BeanPropertyRowMapper(MyVersion.class));
```

I have few doubts regarding same.

1) Will the annotation be applied  like `@NotNull @Size(max = 255)` if i use BeanPropertyRowMapper or CustomRowMapper? Since i am moving away from entity.

2)When using BeanPropertyRowMapper I get below exception.

```
caused by: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type [java.sql.Timestamp] to required type [java.util.Calendar] for property 'createdDate'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.sql.Timestamp] to required type [java.util.Calendar] for property 'createdDate': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:591)
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertForProperty(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:603)
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:449)
```

Answer (score -2):

Change the `Calendar` to `Date` and remove the `@Temporal` and `@DateTimeFormat` annotations.